# Can I get album art for songs only on my iPod?

Tags: ipod, album-art

I have an iPod Classic (the 160 gig one) that I use, and I want to have album art for all of the songs.

Problem is, I cannot just use the "Get Album Art" option on iTunes, because that will only find art for songs currently on that particular computer, and I have many songs on my iPod that are not on my computer.

Short of manually adding the art to every album (like I have been doing), is there a way I can get iTunes (or any other program) to go through my iPod and find the appropriate album art for the songs there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for iTunes to know what is on your iPod if you manage it manually. So the answer is NO.

I assume you are aware that you risk losing all your iPod-only tracks in case your iPods breaks down, gets damaged or stolen. So it may be a good idea to get all tracks into iTunes (and your computer) anyway.